# Why is this code so CPU and memory intensive?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, optimization

Why does this code takes 0.32 CPU hours and has an avreage memory of 24.6 MBytes?
The page refreshes about 30 times until it stops because there are no more datastore entities.

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        found = False
        q = MyModel.all(keys_only=True).fetch(1000)
        if len(q):
            self.response.out.write("Deleted %d MyModel entries" % len(q))
            found = True
            db.delete(q)

        q = MyModel2.all(keys_only=True).fetch(1000)
        if len(q):
            self.response.out.write("Deleted %d MoModel2 entries" % len(q))
            found = True
            db.delete(q)

        if found:
            self.response.out.write('<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0"/>')
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there something I can do to speed it up and use less memory?

Thank you

Comment: I am not familiar with the `webapp` package you are using but your WSGIApplication is `MainHandler` while the code shown here is `ResetHandler`. Are they the same?

Comment: This is the sort of thing that you almost certainly want to do with taskqueue chaining rather than refreshes in a web browser, but yes, deletes in App Engine are CPU intensive.

Comment: Agree with Wooble. Also, if this is not a scheduled thing but rather something you manually invoke, you can use Datastore Admin to delete all entities of a kind. (just a pointer, not saying it would be cheaper in terms of CPU hours)

Comment: Fixed code, and using tasks won't make it less cpu intensive.

Comment: @Shedokan No, but it will make it it less of a hack.

Comment: Also, note that doing a repeated fetch-and-delete like this is O(n^2) due to tombstoned entities; you should use cursors instead.

Comment: But tumbstoned entities still don't show up right? and if so using a cursor won't work since all entities I fetch are "deleted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by testing that I can lower the CPU usage by 3 times only by fetching 200 entries at a time:

```
q = MyModel.all(keys_only=True)
for i in xrange(0, 1000, 200):
    db.delete(q.fetch(200))
```

Fetching 100 results at a time actually is slower than fetching 200 at a time.
But I'll check into the mapreduce, but I don't think that this is a thing

Comment: I'm highly skeptical this reduces the total CPU usage - you're still fetching and deleting the same number of entities. Have you tried running appstats on it?

Answer (score 0):

Seconding task queues. Using [mapreduce](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/) to delete entities is a common practice. It'll manage the tasks for you.

A micro optimization is to make one `webapp.WSGIApplication` and reuse it from a class variable, rather than creating a new one every time `main()` is invoked.